# ASP.NET MVC5 always returns HTTP500 regardless of exception when <customErrors> is turned on

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception

Setup:

- The HandleErrorAttribute has been removed and all filters cleared.
- Exceptions are not being captured or handled in the Global.asax

The web.config setup for IIS errors is as follows:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultPath="/StaticErrors/Default.html" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
         <clear />
         <error statusCode="400" path="/myCustomErrors/Http400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
         <error statusCode="401" path="/myCustomErrors/Http401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
         <error statusCode="403" path="/myCustomErrors/Http403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
         <error statusCode="404" path="/myCustomErrors/Http404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
         <error statusCode="500" path="/myCustomErrors/Http500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      </httpErrors>
```

This works normally, however, if I add the following customErrors code - then any error, such as a Bad Request or Not found will *always* cause the error 500 page to show up. A HttpException is treated as an unhandled exception for some reason.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/StaticErrors/Default.html" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
         <error redirect="~/myCustomErrors/Http400" statusCode="400" />
         <error redirect="~/myCustomErrors/Http401" statusCode="401" />
         <error redirect="~/myCustomErrors/Http403" statusCode="403" />
         <error redirect="~/myCustomErrors/Http404" statusCode="404" />
         <error redirect="~/myCustomErrors/Http500" statusCode="500" />
   </customErrors>
```

**What issues oculd be affected by disabling the ASP.NET error handling in this way in an MVC only application.**

Comment: Try removing the `~`

Comment: With or without the ~ didn't make any difference.  I thought perhaps there was a further error loading the MVC based exception page. But Failed Request Tracing shows nothing. Navigating to the MVC error page directly works correctly also. When customErrors is included '/myCustomErrors/Http500' is always executed.

Comment: Try `500.100` status code instead of `500` in your custom error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was only able to solve this by efffectively re-writing the default error handling capacity using the Global.asax file and the Application_Error method.

```
protected void Application_Error()
      {
         var errorCodeToUse = 500;

         var currentException = Server.GetLastError();
         if (currentException != null)
         {
            var httpException = currentException as System.Web.HttpException;

            if (httpException != null)
            {
               errorCodeToUse = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            }
         }

         var currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
         RequestContext requestContext = null;

         if (currentContext.CurrentHandler != null)
         {
            requestContext = ((MvcHandler)currentContext.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;
         }

         if (requestContext == null)
         {
            requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), new RouteData());
         }

         requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Error";

         switch (errorCodeToUse)
         {
            case 400:
               requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Http400";
               break;
            case 401:
               requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Http401";
               break;
            case 403:
               requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
               break;
            case 404:
               requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
               break;
            case 405:
               requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Http405";
               break;
            case 429:
               requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Http429";
               break;
            default:
               requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Http500";
               break;
         }

         var factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
         var controller = factory.CreateController(requestContext, "Error");
         controller.Execute(requestContext);
         currentContext.Server.ClearError();

      }
```